# Phase modulation of beat notes between two large phase different source

Tags: experimental-physics, laser, squeezed-states

I am working on the following experiment: I send a CW laser (whose path has a fiber stretcher can be modulated by a function generator to change fiber length periodically) and a Menlo source (frequency comb with spacing 100 MHz) to a 50:50 coupler then to an auto-balanced photo detector. The CW laser is frequency and phase locked to the Menlo source but there is a 15 MHz difference (i.e., there is a constant/stable frequency difference between two source). I checked on the ESA at 10 MHz (noise floor frequency) with zero-span mode but I cannot see any modulation signal. I wonder whether the 15MHz frequency difference is too large to see anything.

(Note: Previously I divide the CW source (or Menlo comb) with a 50:50 and make two signals beat with themselves. By adding the same fiber stretcher and modulation I can see clear modulation signal at 10 MHz on ESA)

Comment: I dont get it...you are trying to see an RF signal at 10 MHz although the beat is at 15MHz? That's what I understand by what you describe, that you "zoom in" at 10 MHz. But if the beat is at 15 MHz, why would you expect a signal at 10? Or could you describe everything better?

Comment: Or do you mean that you add a 10 MHz modulation via the function generator, and that is the signal you are looking at? Because if that is so, then of course it works if you use the same source (either CW or ML laser alone) but not when you try to beat the two. The frequency of the CW laser and that of the ML do not overlap. You could maybe see the 15 MHz beat between the two, and perhaps side-bands to that beat with the 10 MHz, maybe (5 and 25MHz). But I doubt you would see anything at 10MHz. Did you try to make a quick simulations to check which beats appear?

Comment: Thanks Andrade for the kind reply. Yes, I zoomed at 10MHz because it is a noise floor: I am doing some squeezing experiment and thus I want to see the periodically changed noise. Previously I used one source (either CW and Menlo), and divided it as two by a 50: 50, and added the fiber stretcher to one path then combine them again with another 50:50. In this case, I can see the periodically-changed noise floor at 10 MHz on ESA (when fiber stretcher was modulated). I just wonder for two sources, whether locking is not enough and they must be at exactly same frequency.